# Replacing <h2> tags with <p> tags, every other <h2> is skipped

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an assignment and I have ran into some issues. We have to essentially convert an `<h2>` tag using javascript into a `<p>` tag while making sure it maintains all of its attributes.

I have come up with the following

```
var numElements = document.getElementsByTagName("h2").length;
for (i=0; i<numElements; i++){
    var curr = document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[i];
    var updated = document.createElement("p");
    for (j = 0; j < document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[i].attributes.length; j++){
        updated.setAttribute(curr.attributes.item(j).name, curr.attributes.item(j).value);
    }
    updated.innerHTML = curr.innerHTML;
    curr.parentNode.replaceChild(updated, curr);
}
```

Now this somewhat works, but I am not sure why I am getting issues with it. The bug that happens is that this only works on every other `<h2>` tag. So if I have 3 tags within a body, it will only perform this function on first and third tags.

I am not looking for a jQuery answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your second trip through the loop, `i == 1`, so you'll grab the second element from the list.

But it's a new list, that no longer includes the element you've already replaced. The *old* second element is now at `i == 0`, never to be touched.

The easiest way to avoid this? Work the list backwards:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
var numElements = elements.length;

for (i = numElements - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var curr = elements[i];
  var updated = document.createElement("p");

  for (j = 0; j < curr.attributes.length; j++){
    updated.setAttribute(curr.attributes.item(j).name, curr.attributes.item(j).value);
  }

  updated.innerHTML = curr.innerHTML;
  curr.parentNode.replaceChild(updated, curr);
}
```

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
var numElements = elements.length;

for (i = numElements - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var curr = elements[i];
  var updated = document.createElement("p");

  for (j = 0; j < curr.attributes.length; j++) {
    updated.setAttribute(curr.attributes.item(j).name, curr.attributes.item(j).value);
  }

  updated.innerHTML = curr.innerHTML;
  curr.parentNode.replaceChild(updated, curr);
}
```

```css
.something {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h2>The first h2</h2>

<h2 style="text-decoration: underline">And the second</h2>

<h3 class="something">And the third</h3>
```